# Central "/home" using SSHFS?

Tags: nfs, sshfs, home-directory

The standard way to setup a central "/home" directory on a Linux workstation is using NFS.  The problem is that I don't like the lack of real security in NFS.  So instead I want to try to use SSHFS.  SSHFS in-and-of itself works fine, the problem is with mounting it at boot.  If I add a line to "/etc/fstab" for the SSHFS share, the workstation complains that it can't contact the SSH server.  This is true because the "/etc/fstab" lines are executed before networking is actually up!

Right now I am using the following init script to mount "/home":

```
#!/bin/sh

# Mounts "/home"  over SSHFS at boot

start () {
    while true; do
        ping -c 1 "10.0.0.200" 1> /dev/null

        if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
            break
        fi

        sleep 1
    done

    sshfs root@10.0.0.200:/home/ /home/ -o transform_symlinks,allow_other,nonempty,hard_remove
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start}"
        exit 1

esac
```

Basically it pings the SSH server once per second until it can connect, then it mounts the SSHFS share.

My question is: **Is there a more direct and less "hack-ish" way to make "/etc/fstab" wait until there is an active network connection before attempting to mount "/home"?**

An alternative idea I had, was adding the "sshfs root@10.0.0.200:/home/ /home/ -o transform_symlinks,allow_other,nonempty,hard_remove" line as an "post-up" script in "/etc/network/interfaces", but that still feels wrong.

Environment:

**Server OS:** Ubuntu Server Edition 10.04

**Client OS:** Ubuntu Desktop 10.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to add the `_netdev` option to delay mounting until the network has been enabled:

```
sshfs#root@10.0.0.200:/home/ /home/ fuse transform_symlinks,allow_other,_netdev,nonempty,hard_remove 0 0
```

You can also put your script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` or the mount command in `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Adding "_netdev" absolutely fixed it!  Thank you for both the answer and the quick response time.